# Moxy XPath local-name() support

Tags: xml, jaxb, moxy

I'm trying to use the EclipseLink Moxy library to extract values from XML messages via XPath. My problem is that I do not know in advance the XML namespace prefixes that will be used in the messages, so I need to specify XPaths that can find elements regardless of the prefix used.

Standard XPath supports the `local-name()` function for this purpose, but I think Moxy only handles a sub-set of XPath which does not seem to include `local-name`. Can anyone suggest another approach?

Comment: You say you don't know the _prefixes_, but do you know what namespace URI(s) they will be bound to? Moxy uses the prefix bindings from the `@XmlSchema`, not the input document.

Comment: Yes, I know the URIs - thanks! I will experiment @XmlSchema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the `@XmlPath` annotation, MOXy leverages the prefix to namespace mappings that are defined in the package level `@XmlSchema` annotation.  The prefixes don't need to match what is in the XML document or XML Schema.

You can find a full example on my blog:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/09/xpath-based-mapping-geocode-example.html

Comment: Great, thanks! And if I am using an external xml bindings file rather than annotations I guess I can just put the mappings inside <xml-ns> ?